# Is there any ways to get a slope in time series using gradient descent from python?

Tags: python-2.7, time-series, gradient-descent

I'm a newbie in python and machine learning. I'm trying to use gradient descent method(linear regression maybe) to get a slope from temperature and time series of graph in python 2.7 like below

[image]

I'm getting temperature and time values from OpenTSDB, and time value is originally appeared as unix time but I changed it to string with using like below

```
TIME = time.localtime(float(_time));
stime = '%4d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d' % (TIME.tm_year, TIME.tm_mon, TIME.tm_mday, TIME.tm_hour, TIME.tm_min, TIME.tm_sec);
```

Is there any ways to get a slope of graph above using gradient descent?

I tried with this tutorial https://anaconda.org/benawad/gradient-descent/notebook, but doesn't work and gives me an awkward answer of slope.

**EDIT**

```
def plot_line(y, data_points):
        x_values = [i for i in range(int(min(data_points))-1, int(max(data_points))+2)]
        y_values = [y(x) for x in x_values]
        plt.plot(x_values, y_values, 'b')

def summation(y, x_points, y_points):
    total1 = 0
    total2 = 0

    for i in range(1, len(x_points)):
        total1 += y(x_points[i]) - y_points[i]
        total2 += (y(x_points[i]) - y_points[i]) * x_points[i]

    return total1 / len(x_points), total2 / len(x_points)

    m = 0
    b = 0
    y = lambda x : m*x + b;

    learn = 0.1;
    for i in range(5):
     s1, s2 = summation(y, timenum_list, temperature_list)
     m = m - learn * s2
     b = b - learn * s1

    print m;
    print b;

    plt.plot(timenum_list, temperature_list, 'bo')
    title('Time vs Temperature')
    xlabel('Time')
    ylabel('Temperature')
```

I used the above function for gradient descent, but didn't work well.

`timenum_list` is the list of unix time.
`temperature_list` is the list of temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradient descent is an alogrithm to find extremes (minimum or maximum) of a function and the problem is, you do not have a function. All you have is a sequence of points. Now you might try to fit a polynomial to your points and compute the derivative of that function, but that probably would not be too accurate, given your data is 'bumpy', or you would have to use a high degree polynomial.

The second option is linear interpolation: In plain words, take two points and fit a line between them and calculate the slope of that line.

The real question is: what do you need to accomplish in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then I might use what you recommended in second option. :'(

Comment: Out of curiosity - what are you trying to do with the slope? We might think of a better solution ;)

Comment: Um... I want to analyze the values of slope between time and temperature , and what kind of relationship is there when people are in the room or not. :) I just finished plotting interpolation. Now I have to take two points or all points to figure out the value of slope :'(

Comment: Also, I have a simple question, I know that the data is 'bumpy'. Can I also use Gaussian filtering method in that data? :)